# Title not centered on titlepage beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

Do you know how I can get my text centered on my titlepage? My background is centered so I dont understand why the text is not (it is slightly on the right). Maybe it is because I use the Berkeley theme which has a sidebar on the left. Thanks [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM9k9.png)

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos} % package for the positioning
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{transparent}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(-2.1cm,-1.6cm)
\includegraphics[height=1.6cm,width=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{images/logo.jpg}
\end{textblock*}}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{15mm}(9.23cm,-1.62cm)
\textblockcolour{white}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1.6cm,width=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{images/sonaca.png}
\end{textblock*}}


\title{\textcolor{beige}{Development and characterization of a gradient structured material elaborated by direct deposition additive manufacturing}}
\author{Corongiu Chiara}
\date{\today}
\institute{University of Liege\\ Faculty of Applied Sciences}

% position the logo
\definecolor{uliege}{RGB}{000,112,127}
\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{230,230,225}
\definecolor{facsa}{RGB}{248,170,000}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=uliege}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(-2.1cm,-1.6cm)
%\includegraphics[height=1.6cm,width=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{images/logo.jpg}
\end{textblock*}}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{15mm}(9.23cm,-1.62cm)
\textblockcolour{white}
\centering
%\includegraphics[height=1.6cm,width=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{images/sonaca.png}
\end{textblock*}}


\title{Development and characterization of a gradient structured material elaborated by direct deposition additive manufacturing}
\author{CORONGIU Chiara}
\date{\today}

% position the logo

\definecolor{uliege}{RGB}{000,112,127}
\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{230,230,225}
\definecolor{facsa}{RGB}{248,170,000}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=uliege}
\begin{document}
%{
  %\usebackgroundtemplate{{ \begin{picture}(0,250)
 % \transparent{0.25} \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{images/uliege.jpg}    \end{picture}}}
\begin{frame}[plain]

\maketitle
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.32\textwidth}@{}}
Supervisors: & Mertens A. \\
& Maurizi Enrici T. \\
& Marchal Y. \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{frame}
%}
\begin{frame}{The title of the frame}
hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: help :( my presentation is on monday

Comment: I believe this is too late,but this is very much related to the Berkeley theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can shift the content of your title page by `.5\beamersidebarwidth`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos} % package for the positioning
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{transparent}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(-2.1cm,-1.6cm)
\includegraphics[height=1.6cm,width=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{images/logo.jpg}
\end{textblock*}}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{15mm}(9.23cm,-1.62cm)
\textblockcolour{white}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=1.6cm,width=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{images/sonaca.png}
\end{textblock*}}


\title{\textcolor{beige}{Development and characterization of a gradient structured material elaborated by direct deposition additive manufacturing}}
\author{Corongiu Chiara}
\date{\today}
\institute{University of Liege\\ Faculty of Applied Sciences}

% position the logo
\definecolor{uliege}{RGB}{000,112,127}
\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{230,230,225}
\definecolor{facsa}{RGB}{248,170,000}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=uliege}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(-2.1cm,-1.6cm)
%\includegraphics[height=1.6cm,width=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{images/logo.jpg}
\end{textblock*}}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{15mm}(9.23cm,-1.62cm)
\textblockcolour{white}
\centering
%\includegraphics[height=1.6cm,width=1.6cm,keepaspectratio]{images/sonaca.png}
\end{textblock*}}


\title{Development and characterization of a gradient structured material elaborated by direct deposition additive manufacturing}
\author{CORONGIU Chiara}
\date{\today}

% position the logo

\definecolor{uliege}{RGB}{000,112,127}
\definecolor{beige}{RGB}{230,230,225}
\definecolor{facsa}{RGB}{248,170,000}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=uliege}
\begin{document}
%{
  %\usebackgroundtemplate{{ \begin{picture}(0,250)
 % \transparent{0.25} \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{images/uliege.jpg}    \end{picture}}}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\hspace*{-.5\beamersidebarwidth}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\maketitle
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hspace{3pt}}p{.32\textwidth}@{}}
Supervisors: & Mertens A. \\
& Maurizi Enrici T. \\
& Marchal Y. \\
\end{tabular}%
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
%}
\begin{frame}{The title of the frame}
hello
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]